# standalone node scripts needs clustering?

Tags: node.js

I have node standalone workers for data processing.
Depend upon my server capability, I will be running multiple instances of worker 
so my question is, do I need to include clustering in my worker, 
because clustering main task is to make use of multiple cores of cpu but it holds true only if we are serving http requests

But in my case if I am running 4 instances and then each instance will follow clustering, so I think its not recommended to use clustering for standalone scripts

Comment: What do you mean by 'clustering'?

Comment: [node cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)
The cluster module allows you to easily create child processes that all share server ports.

Comment: I think that depends on the work you do. If you do CPU-heavy work, then probably you won't want clustering as your 4 processes will heavily utilize you CPU. If it's not CPU-heavy work, multiple instances can speed up your calculations. But I'd vote for testing first and checking what performs better for you

Comment: yeah thanx. indeed testing needed.
but assume that we are serving http request which involves heavy work in that case too we will be using clusters. so actual use case is not clear

Answer (score 0):

The built-in cluster module would be useful in this case, but certainly not necessary.  If you have some queue that each instance can pull from without conflict, then you're probably already running as well as you can.

If you want to manage/broker the work for the child workers, then you can use the cluster module to start sub processes and hand out the tasks from your master process.